# SDL 2.0 source has 1.3 in it?

Tags: android, iphone, sdl, sdl-2

I'm playing around with the SDL 2.0 source code and noticed it has another SDL folder within it that claims to be version 1.3.

I'm interested in it because it has source for android, iphone and a few others.
The stable version , 1.2, seems to be quite different.

My question is this,

[SDL wiki link](http://wiki.libsdl.org/moin.cgi/MigrationGuide#Backward-compatibility)

This link speaks of SDL_compat.c which may allow code to work for both 1.2 and 2.0.
Is this the version I should be using, and should I be coding they way the 2.0 API suggest?
I want my code to target as many platforms as possible including android, and iphone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2.0 is just 1.3 with the 1.2 compatibility layer stripped out.

Check the [mailing list](https://web.archive.org/web/20120302041751/http://lists.libsdl.org/pipermail/sdl-libsdl.org/2012-January/083550.html):

> From: Sam Lantinga
> Subject: [SDL] Creating SDL2
>
> I'm in the process of switching over SDL 1.3 to SDL2.  It'll be a lengthy process because there's a lot of documentation that refers to SDL 1.3, but I wanted to give everyone a heads up.
>
> One of the implications of this is that I'm removing the compatibility layer, and future SDL_* libraries are also going to switch to SDL2, e.g. SDL2_image, etc.
>
> Cheers!