# Setting OGL Major version in SDL leads to error

Tags: c, opengl, gcc, sdl, opengl-3

I'm currently trying to get down OpenGL with C.
I have the current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define null (void*)0

#define GL3_PROTOTYPES 1
#include <GL/gl3.h>

#include <SDL.h>
#define PROGRAM_NAME "Tutorial1"

void sdldie(const char *msg)
{
    printf("%s: %s\n", msg, SDL_GetError());
    SDL_Quit();
    exit(1);
}

void checkSDLError(int line)
{
    #ifndef NDEBUG
        const char *error = SDL_GetError();
        if(*error != '\0')
        {
            printf("SDL Error: %s\n", error);
            if(&line != null)
                printf(" + line: %i\n", line);
            SDL_ClearError();
        }
    #endif
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SDL_Window *mainwindow; //window handle
    SDL_GLContext maincontext; //opengl context handle

    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)//initialize video subsystem
        sdldie("Unable to initialize SDL"); //DIE ON ERROR

    //request OGL 3.2 context (default to SDL core profile)
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 2);

    //turn on double buffering with a 24 bit Z buffer
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24);

    mainwindow = SDL_CreateWindow(PROGRAM_NAME, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
    512, 512, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if(!mainwindow)
        sdldie("Unable to create window");

    checkSDLError(__LINE__);

    //create an opengl context and attach it to the window
    maincontext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(mainwindow);
    checkSDLError(__LINE__);

    //VSync, turn it off later
    SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(1);

    //clear buffer with red background
    glClearColor(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    //swap back buffer to the front
    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(mainwindow);
    //wait 2 secs
    SDL_Delay(2000);

    //repeat with green
    glClearColor(0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    //swap back buffer to the front
    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(mainwindow);
    //wait 2 secs
    SDL_Delay(2000);

    //delete all dis shit
    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(maincontext);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(mainwindow);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Notice the line where we select an OGL version (in main, after initializing video)...
When I do it as in the code here, I wind up with an error:

```
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadFBConfig
  Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  34 ()
  Serial number of failed request:  166
  Current serial number in output stream:  165
```

The line causing this is specifically:

```
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
```

When it's commented out, things work perfectly (but probably with another OGL version D:)

I'm using the latest version of the FOSS Radeon driver (on Arch), SDL2.0 HG version, latest stable GLX and gl3.h has been manually downloaded... on arch linux and gcc version 4.7.2

Any idea why this is happening (/how to get rid of it)?
And is setting that attribute necessary?

Comment: "*Any idea why this is happening (/how to get rid of it)?*" Have you considered that SDL 2.0 isn't released yet? Also, does your hardware&drivers support GL 3.2?

Comment: @NicolBolas
My hardware supports up to GL 3.3.
I'm pretty sure Radion supports up to GL 4.2... and the fact that SDL2.0 isn't released yet doesn't change that it's a rename of SDL-1.3, which has been used by an extensive amount of people (to use SDL with GL 3+)

Comment: It's not a rename of SDL 1.3. And the fact that it's unreleased means that it may have *bugs* in it. Like this one. Also, what do your *drivers* support? Since you're on Linux, run `glxinfo`.

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235539/sdl-2-0-source-has-1-3-in-it), SDL 2.0 is the same as 1.3 without 1.2 compatability. I checked on my other machine (with a much more powerful nvidia card and the proprietary drivers) and it worked fine.
From this I conclude that you're completely right and it was, in fact, the FOSS radeon driver.  
Can you please direct me towards the source for SDL 1.3 and write an answer saying "it's your driver, also, SDL 2.0 is buggy, check out 1.3 found *here*" so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

SDL2 isn't released yet and can contain critical bugs. In your case a bug in SDL_GL_CreateContext.

There was a commit made to address this problem on 10 March 2013 :[SDL_GL_CreateContext() causes fatal X11 protocol errors that should just be caught instead](http://lists.libsdl.org/pipermail/commits-libsdl.org/2013-March/006381.html)

Mine succeeds in creating a OpenGl 3.2 Context with the latest SDL2 commits.